# Flutter/dart: The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'WelcomeScreen'

Tags: flutter, dart

In 2nd dart file I have a class 'WelcomeScreen' with property-

```
  String id = 'welcome_screen';
```

I want to use it in 1st dart file and this is how I am doing it-

```
  initialRoute: WelcomeScreen().id,
  routes: {
    WelcomeScreen().id : (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
```

And then for id, flutter throws an error - The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'WelcomeScreen'

Comment: Use `static const String id = 'welcome_screen';`. Then `initialRoute: WelcomScreeen.id`

Answer (score 1):

Make the id a `static const` field and use it without `WelcomeScreen` instantiation, i.e.:

```dart
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';
  ...
  initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
  routes: {
    WelcomeScreen.id : (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put inside
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {}
then its will be work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).